# Saving files doesn't save a file

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that writes an error log to a file, but when I ask to save that file, just nothing happens (not even exceptions). What do I do wrong?

"Save" button actionListener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String savePath = getSavePath();

    try {
        saveFile(savePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And the three file methods:

```
private String getSavePath() {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

    fc.showOpenDialog(this);

    return fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

}

private void saveFile(String path) throws IOException {
    File outFile = createFile(path);

    FileWriter out = null;

    out = new FileWriter(outFile);

    out.write("Hey");

    out.close();

}

private File createFile(String path) {
    String fileName = getLogFileName(path);
    while (new File(fileName).exists()) {
        fileCounter++;
        fileName = getLogFileName(path);

    }

    File outFile = new File(fileName);
    try {
        outFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return outFile;

}

private String getLogFileName(String path) {
    return "enchantcalc_err_log_" + fileCounter + ".txt";
}
```

Comment: When you made some debug, did you reach the "click" action ?

Comment: Did you `add()` the `ActionListener` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getLogFileName(...)` function is not doing anything with the path you feed it. Therefore, you are trying to write the file to just `enchantcalc_err_log_#.txt` (with no actual path). Try this instead:

```
private String getLogFileName(String path) {
    return path + "enchantcalc_err_log_" + fileCounter + ".txt";
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I was really confused... Oh and I added a separator between path and the name.

Comment: I had a feeling that you might need it

Answer (score 2):

You are probably just not finding the file.

At the end of your `saveFile`, try this: After

```
out.close();
```

Put a line, like this:

```
out.close();
System.out.println("File saved to: "+outFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

You'll then get the *mistery* path where it was saved.